# When wrong user login ios app is crashing and no log displayed. But in Android is working with out crash. Why?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, flutter-dependencies

When wrong user login ios app is crashing and no log displayed. But  in Android is working with out crash. Why?

```
  Thread 26: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/user/FlutterHome/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_aws_amplify_cognito-1.0.0+7/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterAwsAmplifyCognito.swift, line 275
```

```
Future<dynamic> login(
      {String username,
      String password,
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey}) async {
    return FlutterAwsAmplifyCognito.signIn(username, password)
        .then((SignInResult result) {
      debugPrint('------------------------${result}');
      switch (result.signInState) {
        case SignInState.SMS_MFA:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.PASSWORD_VERIFIER:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.CUSTOM_CHALLENGE:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.DEVICE_SRP_AUTH:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.DEVICE_PASSWORD_VERIFIER:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.DONE:
          break;
        case SignInState.UNKNOWN:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case SignInState.ERROR:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
      }
      return result.codeDetails;
    }).catchError((error) {
      if (error.code == 'Error') {
        globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          content: Text(LocalizationsUtils(
                  Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: AppPreferences().language))
              .errorIncorrectEmailPassword),
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```

[github link](https://github.com/scientifichackers/flutter_cognito_plugin/issues/31)
https://github.com/jonsaw/amazon-cognito-identity-dart

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. There is just a missing return in code.

```
static func signIn(result: @escaping FlutterResult, username: String, password: String) {
    AWSMobileClient.default().signIn(username: username, password: password){(signinResult, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                result(FlutterError(code: "Error", message: "Error signing in", details: error?.localizedDescription))
            }
            return // this return was missing!!!
        }
```

FYI: If you run the Application with Xcode, the debugger will point you to the bug.

PS: the return is missing in every error, so the app might crash on other functionCalls too, for example if you try to get Tokens without being loggedIn.

Comment: I know that What is the solution for this?

Comment: Just fork it or clone it from GitHub and make the fix locally, until they fix it on master.